# JavaFX embed panel into scene with scene's background

Tags: javafx

Although it is hard to explain, I am writting to find a solution. I added a panel to scene which has a background image. But also, I want that panel to grab the part of background picture where it is placed. When I move that panel on runtime, it should move with its background picture part (like selecting part of a picture and dragging in paint). Is it possible?

Thanks in advance (I am sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use another ImageView on the Panel using the same Image used for the Scene background. Then you could set the `viewport` on the Panel's ImageView to match the area from the Scene's ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I solved the problem with same way.

```
var bufferedImage = new BufferedImage( scene.width, scene.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );
scene.renderToImage( bufferedImage );
bufferedImage=bufferedImage.getSubimage(panel.layoutX,panel.layoutY,x,y);
```

with code above, it is possible to get screenshot and its parts.

Thanks.